# Result not displayed when comparison operation returns false

Tags: php

I am trying to display the result of the comparison operation `($a > $b)` which does not display anything for the below code, whereas the operation `($a < $b)` displays the result `1`.

I am wondering why the first operation does not return `0` as it is `false`?

```
<?php
    $a = 1;
    $b = 5;
    print ($a > $b);
    echo "Output";
    print ($a < $b);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's an extremely common misconception. `0` "is" not `false`. `false` is `false`, a boolean. `0` is `0`, a number. `0` loosely equals `false` in a non-type safe comparison.

When you `echo` or `print` `false`, it is being cast to a string. `false` cast to a string is `""`, an empty string. `true` cast to a string is `"1"`, the string "1".

Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting.

Comment: PHP has no objective standard for truth - it plays hard and fast with the truth. Truth is relative, according to PHP. "True and false are whatever I desire."

Comment: @Patashu That's bullcr*p. PHP has perfectly defined [truth tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), you just have to learn them. PHP is not random. It boils down to the following things being *falsey*: `false`, `0`, `'0'`, `''`, `null`, `array()`. Everything else is *truthy*.

Comment: @Patashu That comment also has nothing to do with the topic at hand: *type juggling*.

Comment: You can memorize all of the weird comparison rules in PHP, but it's so easy to get wrong. For example http://phpsadness.com/sad/47 has some of my favourite gotchas, because 'string that contains a number' can suddenly become true when you don't expect it - `"1e1"` being a number for example...

Comment: @Patashu But again, that's [perfectly defined behavior](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types). And again, you need to learn your language, especially if it has a lot of such automagic going on. It's not like you can't do anything about it and are at the mercy of PHP; you just have to know what your operators do and what the rules are. Every language has its type comparison gotchas, complaining about it doesn't make you a good programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Integer comparison ($a < $b) has return type **boolean**, which can be *true* or *false*.
*print* works in such way that it prints "1" for *true* and nothing for *false*.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the way in which PHP handles false values.

`echo ($a > $b)` will also output nothing.

To have your statement output 0 for a false condition you need to cast to an integer:

```
print (int)($a > $b);
```